# Intellij starts with insert key on

Tags: intellij-idea, insert, keyboard

i have moved to intellij 14 (using centos 7).

Each time that i open a file using intellij, it opens it when the 'insert' key is pressed.

how do i change it? can it be a problem with the centos? (when opening a new gedit document it appears to be ok)

thank you

Answer (score 14):

The problem was the ideaVim intellij plugin.

after disabling it, the problem was solved and the 'tab' key started working for multiple lines selection.

[Intellij 14 weird editor/cursor behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788552/intellij-14-weird-editor-cursor-behaviour)

cheers

Answer (score 3):

Disable the ideaVim plugin worked for me. Ctrl+Alt+S opens up Settings/preferences dialog box, uncheck the ideaVim plugin